# cc avenue payment gateway integration error in core php

Tags: php, payment-gateway, ccavenue

i am using cc avenue payment gateway for my shopping site 
i have integrate Non-Seamless method for payment, its working fine when i go for payment but after redirect i got this error every time

```
security error. illegal access detected
```

but after successful transaction ccavenue redirect to my redirection page at that time i got that error with some data with unreadable format

this is my file for fill information

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
 window.onload = function() {
  var d = new Date().getTime();
  document.getElementById("tid").value = d;
 };
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form method="post" name="customerData" action="ccavRequestHandler.php">
  <table width="40%" height="100" border='1' align="center"><caption><font size="4" color="blue"><b>Integration Kit</b></font></caption></table>
   <table width="40%" height="100" border='1' align="center">
    <tr>
     <td>Parameter Name:</td><td>Parameter Value:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2"> Compulsory information</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>TID :</td><td><input type="text" name="tid" id="tid" readonly /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Merchant Id :</td><td><input type="text" name="merchant_id" value="my_merchant id"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Order Id :</td><td><input type="text" name="order_id" value="<?php echo  $_REQUEST['order_id']; ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Amount :</td><td><input type="text" name="amount" value="1.00"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Currency :</td><td><input type="text" name="currency" value="INR"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Redirect URL :</td><td>
<input type="text" name="redirect_url" value="http://cakemyday.in/payment/CCA/ccavResponseHandler.php"/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Cancel URL :</td><td>
<input type="text" name="cancel_url" value="http://cakemyday.in/payment/CCA/ccavResponseHandler.php"/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>Language :</td><td><input type="text" name="language" value="EN"/></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td colspan="2">Billing information(optional):</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>Billing Name :</td><td><input type="text" name="billing_name" value="Charli"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>Billing Address :</td><td><input type="text" name="billing_address" value="Room no 1101, near Railway station Ambad"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>Billing City :</td><td><input type="text" name="billing_city" value="Indore"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>Billing State :</td><td><input type="text" name="billing_state" value="MP"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>Billing Zip :</td><td><input type="text" name="billing_zip" value="425001"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>Billing Country :</td><td><input type="text" name="billing_country" value="India"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>Billing Tel :</td><td><input type="text" name="billing_tel" value="9876543210"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>Billing Email :</td><td><input type="text" name="billing_email" value="test@test.com"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td colspan="2">Shipping information(optional)</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>Shipping Name :</td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_name" value="Chaplin"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>Shipping Address :</td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_address" value="room no.701 near bus stand"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>shipping City :</td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_city" value="Hyderabad"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>shipping State :</td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_state" value="Andhra"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>shipping Zip :</td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_zip" value="425001"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>shipping Country :</td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_country" value="India"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>Shipping Tel :</td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_tel" value="9876543210"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>Merchant Param1 :</td><td><input type="text" name="merchant_param1" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['order_cake_id']; ?>"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>Merchant Param2 :</td><td><input type="text" name="merchant_param2" value="additional Info."/></td>
          </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Merchant Param3 :</td><td><input type="text" name="merchant_param3" value="additional Info."/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Merchant Param4 :</td><td><input type="text" name="merchant_param4" value="additional Info."/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Merchant Param5 :</td><td><input type="text" name="merchant_param5" value="additional Info."/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Promo Code :</td><td><input type="text" name="promo_code" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Vault Info. :</td><td><input type="text" name="customer_identifier" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
           <td></td><td><INPUT TYPE="submit" value="CheckOut"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
       </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

this is my request handler file code

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> Non-Seamless-kit</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>

<?php include('Crypto.php')?>
<?php 

 error_reporting(0);
 
 $merchant_data='mykey';
 $working_key='my working key';//Shared by CCAVENUES
 $access_code='my access code';//Shared by CCAVENUES
 
 
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
  $merchant_data.=$key.'='.$value.'&';
 }

 $encrypted_data=encrypt($merchant_data,$working_key); // Method for encrypting the data.

?>
<form method="post" name="redirect" action="https://world.ccavenue.com/servlet/ccw.CCAvenueController"> 
<?php
echo "<input type=hidden name=encRequest value=$encrypted_data>";
echo "<input type=hidden name=access_code value=$access_code>";
?>
</form>
</center>
<script language='javascript'>document.redirect.submit();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

so where i am wrong with this code please help me

thanks

Comment: please check your response handler file for workingkey

Answer (score 2):

please add key in response file while will get response from payment gateway